# gradle creating jar does not work with 'implementation' depedencies

Tags: java, gradle, grpc, grpc-java

I am new to gradle and trying to generate a jar from a simple hello world java [grpc](https://grpc.io) 
and below is my build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'com.google.protobuf' version '0.8.12'
    id 'idea'
    id 'java'
}

version '1.0'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    maven { // The google mirror is less flaky than mavenCentral()
        url "https://maven-central.storage-download.googleapis.com/repos/central/data/" }
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.29.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.29.0'
    implementation 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.29.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}


protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.11.0"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.29.0'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/grpc'
            srcDirs 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
        }
    }
}

startScripts.enabled = false

task helloWorldServer(type: CreateStartScripts) {
    mainClassName = 'com.javagrpc.HelloWorldServer'
    applicationName = 'hello-world-server'
    outputDir = new File(project.buildDir, 'tmp')
    classpath = startScripts.classpath
}

applicationDistribution.into('bin') {
    from(helloWorldServer)
    fileMode = 0755
}

distZip.shouldRunAfter(build)

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.examples.javagrpc.HelloWorldServer',
        'Class-Path': configurations.runtime.files.collect { "lib/$it.name" }.join(' ')
    }

    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA', 'META-INF/*.SF','META-INF/*.DSA'
}
```

I started running into issue when I run the task 'gradle jar' it builds a jar inside build/libs when I run the jar its fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/grpc/BindableService`
I unpacked the jar and didn't find the grpc dependencies inside it.
I tried running the generated files directly

```
./build/install/java-grpc/bin/hello-world-server
```

and it works as expected.
To resolve the jar issue, I decided to change the above dependencies from **implementation** to **api** as below.

```
dependencies {
    api 'io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:1.29.0'
    api 'io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:1.29.0'
    api 'io.grpc:grpc-stub:1.29.0'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Now everything works as expected the dependencies are inside the jar and I can run the jar.
But I am not sure whether I shall be using **api** or not in my dependencies since the official [example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/build.gradle#L30) does not uses it?
Maybe I am not correctly generating the jar and it can be generated just with dependencies **implementation** any help or pointers is highly appreciated.

Comment: can you try run `gradle build`, and then check if there is any jar file generated in the build/libs directory?

Comment: @keweixia gradle build also generates the same as with the jar command and it does not have the grpc library inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `jar` task modification you use does not take advantage of the new dependency configurations.

Instead of collection the dependencies from `compile`, you really want to collect the dependencies from `runtimeClasspath` in your uber JAR. After all, in order to run, it will need all dependencies declared in `implementation` but `runtimeOnly` as well. See [the documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/6.4/userguide/java_plugin.html#tab:configurations) to better understand the relationship between these configurations.

```
jar {
    ...
    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
    ...
}
```